# How to show that $S(n, q)$ is a chamber complex?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

A simplicial complex is called a chamber complex if any two chambers of the simplicial complex is connected by a gallery. A simplicial complex is a family of finite subsets $X$ of a set of vertices $V$, such that if $F_1 \in X$ and $F_2 \subseteq F_1$, then $F_2 \in X$. If $F\in X, |F|=i+1$, then we say $\dim F = i$. Maximal faces of $X$ are called chambers. Codimension 1 faces are called walls. A gallery is a sequence of chambers $C_1, \ldots, C_n$ such that $C_i \cap C_{i+1}$ is a wall for each $i$.

Now define flag complex $S(n, q)$ as follows. Let $F_q$ be the field of $q$ elements and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Let vertices ($0$-dimensional faces) of $S(n, q)$ are all subspaces of $F_q^n$ different from $\{0\}$ and $F_q^n$. The general faces of $S(n, q)$ is of the form $\{W_0, \ldots, W_i\}$, where $W_0 \subset W_1 \subset \cdots \subset W_i \subset F_q^n$, $W_0, \ldots, W_i$ are subspaces of $F_q^n$ with dimension $i+1$. If $i=n-2$, then we obtain a maximal face. The dimension of $S(n, q)$ is $n-2$.

Therefore the chambers of $S(n, q)$ is of the form $\{W_0, \ldots, W_{n-2}\}$, where $W_0 \subset W_1 \subset \cdots \subset W_i \subset F_q^n$, $W_0, \ldots, W_{n-2}$ are subspaces of $F_q^n$ with dimension $n-1$. Suppose that we have two chambers $\{W_0, \ldots, W_{n-2}\}$ and $\{W_0', \ldots, W_{n-2}'\}$. How could we show that there is a gallery between them? Thank you very much.

In the case of $n=2$, $S(2, q)$ is a set of $q+1$ one dimensional subspaces of $F_q^2$. The chambers are one dimensional subspaces. Let $v_1, v_2$ be a basis of $F_q^2$. If we take the chambers $F_qv_1$ and $F_qv_2$, then $F_qv_1+F_qv_2$ is a gallery connecting $F_qv_1$ and $F_qv_2$. Is this true?

Comment: For $n = 2$ the vertices of $S(2, q)$ are all $1$-dimensional, so none can contain another one. Walls are empty sets. So the answer to the question at the end is "No". (A good source for a proof of your first question is the book *The Geometry of the Classical Groups* by  *D.E. Taylor*.)